# How to give an error message if no value has been selected after button click in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a selectlist and a button,I need to give an error message if the user clicks the button without selecting a value in the selectlist in AngularJS. I found-out that you need to include required which I did,but how would I include an alert box telling the user that they need to select a value first.Here is my code:
Oh this is how my JS page is structured

HTML

```
 <select  ng-disabled="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId !== undefined"  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories"  required>
            <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
        </select> 

   <button ng-click="Model.StartDowntimeEvent()" id="btnEventStart" class="tooltip">Start</button>
```

JS

```
function Model($http) {
    var self = this;
    self.$http = $http;

 self.StartDowntimeEvent = function () {
//Something
}
}

angular.module('myApp', [])

 .controller('DowntimeController', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.Model = new Model($http);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories"  required>
            <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
        </select> 
<div ng-show="isError">Please select value from select</div>
   <button ng-click="OnClick()" id="btnEventStart" class="tooltip">Start</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.OnClick = function(){
   if($scope.Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId > 0){
       $scope.isError = false;
   }else{
       $scope.isError = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: I just edited my question can you please check it out Volodymyr Bilyachat

Comment: Thanks I did found a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this, it's form validation by angular

```
<form role="form" name="form">
<select name="category" ng-disabled="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId !== undefined"  ng-model="Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId" ng-options="downtimeCategory.CategoryId as downtimeCategory.CategoryName for downtimeCategory in Model.DowntimeCategories"  required>
    <option value="">--SELECT--</option>
</select> 
<span class="help-block" ng-show="form.category.$error.required && !form.category.$pristine && form.category.$error.blur"><p class="text-danger">This field is required</p></span>
<button ng-click="Model.StartDowntimeEvent()" id="btnEventStart" class="tooltip">Start</button>
```

and for your JS

```
$scope.Model.StartDowntimeEvent = function() {

if(Model.CurrentDowntime.CategoryId <= 0) {
    $scope.form.category.$pristine = false;
    $scope.form.category.$error.blur = true;
}

}
```

Comment: I just edited my question can you please check it out @ThomasP1988